# PHP OOP change variable

Tags: php, oop

Is it possible to change a array like this `$email, $firstname, $lastname, $gender` to something like `$this->email, $this->firstname`, more like a loop so I only need to fill in the first array and after the array just be able to use `$this->email` etc

Comment: Why don't you simply write a class and fill the class-memebers (email, firstname, and so on) into `__construct()` function?

Comment: Use an object and define getter and setter classes to interact with an internal array if you want.

Comment: `$object = (object) array('email' => $email, 'firstname' => $firstname, 'lastname' => $lastname, 'gender' => $gender);`.... but using `$this` is only appropriate for methods inside the class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that's possible, take a look at this class:

```
Class MyClass {

   public function __construct($myArray){
      foreach($myArray as $key => $value){
          $this->{$key} = $value;
      }
   }
}

$array = array(
   "email" => "example@example.com",
   "firstname" => "John",
   "lastname" => "Doe",
   "gender" => "male"
);

$class = new MyClass($array);
```

If you do a `var_dump($class)` it will show you the properties with their values.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to put scalar variables into a CLASS there is a class already defined in PHP called stdClass. I assume you ment CLASS as you used the `->`

So instead of loading data to a scalar variable you can do

```
$user = new stdClass();
$user ->email = $_POST['email']; 
$user ->firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$user ->lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$user ->gender = $_POST['gender'];
```

You can then reference each individually as `$user ->$email` and also loop around the whole class using `foreach`

```
foreach ( $user as $field => $value ) {
    echo $field . ' contains the value ' . $value;
}
```

Of course you should sanitize $_POST first.